# Is there a way to run a function in background in an outlook web add-in?

Tags: outlook, office-js, outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

I am currently working on an outlook web add-in.

My add-in is a on message compose one. I'm closing de compose window and trying to run a function afterwards, but the function I want to execute is not executed:

```
Office.context.mailbox.item.close(); //Closing the compose window
executeInBack(); //This is not executed
```

The function is probobly not executed due to the add-in closing before the function could run.

I was wondering if there was an extention point where I cloud always execute a function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Outlook web add-in work under the context of currently displayed item only. So, you need to run your action before the item is closed. Or just use a back-end service which can do the required work using [Graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/use-the-api) after.

Comment: Concur that this is the correct answer.

Comment: But isn't there any extension point that is always running?

Comment: Nope. There are no other mechanisms.

Comment: So for example, if I want to process an email body and then send it in background after I close the compose window. I'm forced to use a back-end service to the the process?

Answer (score 1):

Posting as an answer, as I am unable to leave a comment to the discussion above.

I concur with Eugene; those are the only options that would work for the scenario you're after. If you're able to run the action before the item is closed, a possibility is to use another event to process the email body before it's sent (and while the compose window is active), e.g. onMessageSend (see [Configure your Outlook add-in for event-based activation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/autolaunch#event-based-activation-behavior-and-limitations) for further guidance).

Comment: I already configured my add-in to support events, but when I close the compose window nothing runs anymore. I might have to you an external service. Thanks.